# how to send image mailer using php mail function

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i am trying to send html image mailer using php mail function on linux platform. There is one issue when i am trying to send simple html content then it successfully get delivered to its subscriber. but when i try to send emailer which contains few images then it fails to deliver it. below are two codes 1 by which simple html is delivered. 2 which is not getting delivered.

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

code 2:

```
<?php
    //change this to your email.
    $to = "abhinav@xyz.in";
    $from = "abhinav.1@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Hello! This is HTML email";

    //begin of HTML message
$message= <<<EOF
<html>
  <body bgcolor="#DCEEFC">
    <center>
        <b>Looool!!! I am reciving HTML email......</b> <br>
        <font color="red">Thanks Mohammed!</font> <br>
        <a href="http://www.maaking.com/">* maaking.com</a>
    </center>
      <br><br>*** Now you Can send HTML Email <br> Regards<br>MOhammed Ahmed - Palestine
  </body>
</html>
EOF;
   //end of message
    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    //options to send to cc+bcc
    //$headers .= "Cc: [email]maa@p-i-s.cXom[/email]";
    //$headers .= "Bcc: [email]email@maaking.cXom[/email]";

    // now lets send the email.
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo "Message has been sent....!";
?>
```

Comment: As a tip, sending mails with PHP is not easy. It would be best to use a libary like Swiftmailer which makes the process a lot easier. Look here: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

Comment: thanks Reflic but i need to do it using php . I will look and try to use the documentation u provided. But do you have any idea how can i do it using php...

Comment: possible duplicate: [HEREDOC syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457073/sending-html-email-from-php-with-variables)

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_SL in /root/send_html/sendmailer.php on line 8...this is the error i am getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected the code by which I am able to send image mailer below is the code:

```
<?php
$to= 'abhinav@xyz.com' . ',';
$to .= 'abhinav@gmail.com';
$sub='test1';
$msg= <<<EOF
   <html>
   <body>
   <table>
     <tr>
      <td><img src="http://d32vlg867bsa1v.cloudfront.net/z/prod/w/2/i/zovi-logo2.png"  />
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
EOF;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: <centos_test@example.com>' . "\r\n";


mail($to,$sub,$msg,$headers);
?>
```

I am still working to sent highly customized mailer and will describe how it can once I found how it can be done.